# Conditional Filter on ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I had seen several question about adding conditions to a filter of a ng-repeat, and none of those options had worked for me

I have the following custom filter

```
app.filter('customFilter', function () {
    return function (collection, type, seq) {
        return !collection ? [] : collection.filter(function (item) {
            return (type === 'DL' && item.del_seq === seq) || (type === 'PU' && item.pu_seq === seq)
        });
    }
});
```

And and this is on my directive

```
<tr ng-repear-start="parent in parentCollection">
  <td> Do stuff with parent collection items info </td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat-end="">
   <td colspan="100">
       <table>
           <tr ng-repeat="child in childCollection | customFilter: parent.Type:parent.seq">
              <td>Do stuff with child info</td>
           </tr>
       </table>
   </td>
</tr>
```

And this work perfectly, but I wanted to know, if there a way to do so using a simple filter?

I tried to do the following

```
<tr ng-repeat="child in childCollection | filter: (parent.Type === 'PU' ? child.pu_seq: child.dl_seq) === parent.seq">
```

But it didn't work. Think it's possible without a custom?

Edit: As requested, this a sample JSON and also, adjusted the html for a better idea

```
parentCollection = [{seq: 1, type:'PU'},{seq: 2, type:'PU'},{seq: 3, type:'PU'},{seq: 4, type:'DL'}];
childCollection = [{pu_seq: 1, dl_seq:4},{pu_seq: 2, dl_seq:4},{pu_seq: 3, dl_seq:4}]
```

The outcome would be that, parent[0] will have a detail row with child[0], parent[1] with child[1], parent[2] with child[2] and parent[3] will have the 3 childs as details, as all 3 have a dl_seq:4, and parent[4] is a dl and it's seq it's 4

Comment: post your json here

Comment: @Sajeetharan json added

Answer (score 0):

Try to use filter function in your controller:

```
function itemsFilter(parent) {
    return function(child) {
        return (parent.Type === 'PU' ? child.pu_seq: child.dl_seq) === parent.seq
    };
}
```

And then filter:

```
<tr ng-repeat="child in item.collection | filter: itemsFilter(parent)>
```

Comment: Well, I think I already do something of the sorts with the custom Filter. what I wanted to know is that, If I could achieve the same result with a simple filter sentence, instead of depending of a function or a custom filter, but thanks for the tip, will see if I can use if somewhere else